# add selected value to users profile

Tags: c#, sql, database, insert

Ok I have a button and onclick it reduces the number of select value by 1. That is working, next it adds selected choice to a column in the users profile called Rented.
When I run the code it tells me I am missing a ; from a query, but the code shows no errors.
This is very puzzling to me.
If somebody could point out what im doing wrong it would be great.

**Code**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\ASPNetDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
    {
        da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Rented) VALUES (@Rented) WHERE ([UserName] = ?)", conn);
        string dvdrent = DG_Latest.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rented", dvdrent);

        var myquery = string.Format("UPDATE DVD SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE Title =  ");
        var row = DG_Latest.SelectedRow;
        var title = row.Cells[1].Text;
        myquery = string.Format(myquery + "'{0}'", title);

        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(myquery, conn))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is it moaning about? That would help track down the error.

Comment: highlights da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  the says Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `;` from the sql query. So you need to change it to this.

`myquery = string.Format(myquery + "'{0};'", title);`

Notice the literal semi-colon after the title parameter has been appended to the string `myquery`.

As a side-note it might be easier if you set the `title` first and then created the whole query string in one go using:

```
var row = DG_Latest.SelectedRow;
var title = row.Cells[1].Text;
var myquery = String.Format("UPDATE DVD SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE Title = {0};", title);
```

EDIT: You've missed the semi-colon from the INSERT SQL command as well. You need to have:

```
da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Rented) VALUES (@Rented) WHERE ([UserName] = ?);", conn);
```

Comment: Have you tried it the way I suggest above by setting the query string in one go?

Comment: Error 21 'string' does not contain a definition for 'format' C:\Users\ben\Dropbox\Ben & Andrew\DataBase\members\Default.aspx.cs 57 20 C:\...\members\
Error 20 Cannot use local variable 'row' before it is declared 
Error 22 The name 'myquery' does not exist in the current context 
Error 23 The name 'myquery' does not exist in the current context 
Error 24 The name 'myquery' does not exist in the current

Comment: It's because `string` is the built in type. You probably need to use `String.Format`

Comment: hmm that fixes the string error, im not sure about the myquery error though

Comment: You'll need to do `var myquery = String.Format("UPDATE DVD SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE Title = {0};", title);` to define the variable. Sorry my code wasn't complete, I was just trying to illustrate the missing semi-colon.

Comment: I understand, ok how about Error Cannot use local variable 'row' before it is declared

Comment: Have you moved the declaration of `row` above the declaration of `title` as `row` is used in the initialisation of it. I'll update the answer to show that as well.

Comment: Does this fix the problem then? Please accept the answer if it does. Hopefully it's all working now.

Comment: Ok lol new error when I click on the button to add DVD I get this  Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Title = World War Z'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43780/discussion-between-choc13-and-beep)

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :**  you are not providing the value for Parameter `UserName`.

**Solution :** you need to provide the value for `UserName` parameter in your `INSERT INTO` command.

Try This:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\ASPNetDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
    {
        da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Rented) VALUES (?) WHERE [UserName] = ?", conn);
        string dvdrent = DG_Latest.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;            
        OleDbParameter p1 = new OleDbParameter();
        OleDbParameter p2 = new OleDbParameter();
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(p1);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(p2);
        p1.Value = dvdrent;
        p2.Value = "myusername"; //your username value here   


        var myquery = string.Format("UPDATE DVD SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE Title =  ");
        var row = DG_Latest.SelectedRow;
        var title = row.Cells[1].Text;
        myquery = string.Format(myquery + "'{0}'", title);

        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(myquery, conn))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: very nice @Sudhakar Tillapudi  unfortunately I am still getting Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.

Comment: also could you explain a bit about  the username value part you have commented ?

Comment: @Beep: you have given ` WHERE [UserName] = ?` in your insert into statement right, so you should specify the username value like for which username you want to insert

Comment: This doesn't address the problem that he's missing a `;` from the end of the query string, which is what the SQL error is telling him.

Comment: hmm I think I may have wrote the query wrong. I am trying to get the DVD selection to be posted under the current logged in users profile